# Which has a higher priority while naming: Double or a triple bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Which has higher priority in IUPAC naming: A double or a triple bond? given that both are located at the terminal/equivalent positions in the molecule. 
[image: Pic]

My [chemistry textbook](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/kech205.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjZgaDX747XAhXEuY8KHRscAbwQFgh3MAw&usg=AOvVaw2GJ0S8rouF1ZDyhw0u8XYv) says a double bond has a higher priority than a triple bond but I'm skeptical over it.

[image: pic2]

If someone can provide some more authentic source citing this rule, I'll be highly grateful.

EDIT: Drawing the hydrocarbon linear 
[image: Pic3]

Comment: Here is a wikipedia link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_nomenclature_of_organic_chemistry that refers to the IUPAC publication *Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry* (the Blue Book).

Comment: Please, draw that alkyne linear.

Comment: @orthocresol Edit Made. Thanks for notifying!

Comment: @MaxW The priority table of functional grops given on wikpedia does not have alkene/alkyne in it.

Comment: @orthocresol I didn't knew this has been previously answered. Thanks!

Comment: @orthocresol is it always necessary to make alkynes linear? Are zig zag formulas not allowed for them?

Comment: @Abcd This should be a new question, really. See: https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277 (p 345)